# Dipping Cakepops in Callebaut Callets

Tags: chocolate

I just received my Revolation machine and will be tempering my Callebaut callets in them tonight.

I will be using it mostly for dipping cakepops. I roll them and stick them in the freezer for just a few minutes and then dip them in the chocolate.

I had previously tempered the chocolate in the microwave without using a thermometer and the chocolate came out dull and definitely soft and pliable.

I am using Callebaut Belgian White and Dark Chocolate Callets. **Did I get the right chocolate for this kind of confection?**

**Will the chocolate eventually harden after dipping and become less tacky?** (I place my pops in cello bags)?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you did when you said, you tempered the chocolate by hand? Typically the chocolate dip should be melted to a specific temperature(depending on how dark the chocolate is) and when you dip whatever in, the chocolate should be tempered when it cools down. You shouldn't need to do anything to it with your hands after you dip it.

Comment: Hi Jay,I meant I did not use a tempering machine.  I just basically used the microwave method (without thermometer) and went from there.  What I'm scared of is that I may have bought the wrong type of chocolate for what I intend to use it for :(

Comment: Also, Jay, I bought the "Callebaut Belgian White and Dark Chocolate Callets."

Comment: Liz, I had made several edits to your question to add the additional information you provided in the comments and format it for easier readability. If I changed the meaning of your question in any way, you may edit it farther by clicking on the edit link under the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you probably didn't temper the chocolate correctly the first time. Tempering chocolate can be a really delicate thing and being off by several degrees can affect whether the chocolate is tempered well.

Because your chocolate wasn't tempered correctly, it would not have harden completely. The chocolate's cocoa butter is composed of glycerides of fatty acids that needs to solidify at a certain temperature to ensure a stable formation. It is this stable formation that makes the chocolate firm(non-tacky) and shiny.

Here is a guide to tempering chocolate using a microwave and a thermometer: http://chocomap.com/chocolate-making-tempering.php

I have taken a look at the chocolate you have bought and there should be no reason why it shouldn't temper correctly. Your new Revolation will melt your chocolate at a very precise temperature so your chocolate should come out tempered. It will be shiny and firm.

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you so much for answering back.  So, it sounds like I have the right chocolate for what I intend to use it for.  Now, I am excited to start using my Revolation.  Thanks again!